# c++ / openFrameworks - how to include a class

Tags: c++, class, openframeworks

I'm very new to openFrameworks and c++. I'm compiling an open source project in xcode which is not working, and I would like to use the following class to try and debug what seems to be a path issue:

http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/utils/ofDirectory.html

However, I'm not sure exactly how to include this class, or where to insert my code. Basically I just want to find out where openFrameworks thinks my current directory is, for starters. Like:

```
string path = "."; 
ofDirectory dir(path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a copy of the header file containing the class ofDirectory, ie "ofDirectory.h" you can include it at the top of your .cpp file using `#include "ofDirectory.h"` and you will be able to use the functions associated with it. ofDirectory.h must be in the same folder as your .cpp file, else you will have to provide the path to it as well